# Inactive tab validation in ngbNav

Tags: javascript, html, angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I have a form with two tabs and a save button (outside the tab). The first tab has textbox with required validation. Somehow the "required" validation does not fire when user has opened second tab (i.e. first tab is inactive) and click on save button.

**HTML Code:**

```
<form #frm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSave(frm)" >
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
    <ul ngbNav #nav="ngbNav" class="nav-tabs">
        <li [ngbNavItem]="1">
            <a ngbNavLink>Details</a>
            <ng-template ngbNavContent>
                <input type="number" class="form-control numeric" id="inputNumber" name="inputNumber"
                        [(ngModel)]="inputNumber" required />
    
            </ng-template>
        </li>
        <li [ngbNavItem]="1">
            <a ngbNavLink>Charts</a>
            <ng-template ngbNavContent>
            </ng-template>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

TS Code:

```
onSave(form) {
    if (!form.valid) { // Valid returns true when the user has opened the second tab and click on save
      return
    };
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `[destroyOnHide]="false"` would be a quick fix.
In a long run, it is worth considering [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).

It is flexible and handles any complex scenarios. It is more component code and less HTML markup which is easier to cover with unit tests.

It takes time to master though. A few hours of training or reading the docs would be required.

Answer (score 3):

ngbNav provide feature to keep hidden dom elements in case these are from non-active tabs. In your case, as your element is in another tab, you can keep that in DOM, which can easily be validated.

Need to use `[destroyOnHide]="false"` on ul (where ngbNav is added).

[More Info](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/nav/examples#keep-content)

Answer (score 0):

If the tab is inactive then it's removed from DOM. So the field is not exist and it can't be validated. I would suggest you to have separate field for errors and based on that field show or hide error messages.

Comment: you can use Reactive Forms (a formGroup exist independient) instead Template driven form

Comment: @Eliseo - thanks. It looks like Reactive Forms would be solution for it. Is it a lot of work to convert a template driven form to  Reactive?

Comment: @softwareEngineer - yes, it is not on DOM. Is there anyway to keep it in DOM but invisible? Also, can you please expand on "I would suggest you to have separate field for errors and based on that field show or hide error messages."

Comment: You have a model for inputNumber inside onSave function you can check if inputNumber is filled or not. If not then you can show some message which says to fill that field.

Comment: that means I will have to add duplicate validation. I think there might be a better way to handle this?